# JS: Applying focus effect on an element when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/5/

All I want to achieve is to highlight (e.g adding a background color) the heading (in `<strong> </strong>` tag) of the section-3 when I scroll to section-3.

I'd like to know if there's a way for me to trigger certain events when I'm at a certain section. There must be a thing for this because when you scroll the page manually, you'll notice that, in the navigation menu, link to the section gets selected automatically, as if it was clicked.

Anything helpful will be much appreciated as I've been working on this since yesterday and hav yet to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this using CSS, so I edited the jquery.nav.min.js. (added only 4 lines) It works great now. http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/10/

```
adjustNav=function(a,b,d){
                var sec = a.find("."+d+">a").attr("href");
                $(sec+">strong").css('background','none'); //Find and remove previous highlight of strong  
                a.find("."+d).removeClass(d);b.addClass(d); //ORIGINAL

                sec = b.find("a").attr("href");
                $(sec+">strong").css('background','aqua'); //Find and highlight the strong
};
```

EDIT: Animation added by request:
http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/11/

add `animateSomething` function on top:

```
function animateSomething(sec) {
    if(sec == "#section-2")
        $("#testBlock").animate({
            width:"50%",
            opacity:0.5
        }, 1500);
}
```

add `animateSomething(sec);` at the end of `adjustNav` function.
Voila!

EDIT FINAL: Animate AFTER scroll ends http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/12/

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much. I have a few more questions though. First, how do I make an animation happen when I'm at a specific section. e.g the width of an element would animate to 300px when I'm at section 3? Is there way to code it according to which section you're at?

Comment: First off, it is very hard to modify minified js files :) I had to constantly compare the minified code with this [original js link](https://raw.github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/master/jquery.nav.js). For the extra animation that occurs, do you mean after you **click** on the navigation and the window scrolls to that section? In that case, you would look at `onAfter: function() {` within `handleClick: function(e)`

Comment: Nope, not a click.  While manually scrolling, when you are at section-3, I want to animate an object, a div, an image, anything that has css. Please, is it that hard? When you scroll to and when you're at section-3, the 'Section 3' item in the menu gets selected anyway, so is it impossible to get a thing done when you're at 'a section' By the way, I appreciate your support and generosity, you're so rare:)

Comment: Awesome awesome! Omg thank you Jay Na! You're the best! ^^ Just a small thing: check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/MZWsm/ When duplicating your code and adjust it, only the last one works.

Comment: I edited one last time to animate **AFTER** scrolling ends. Checkout the jsfiddle in the answer. Make sure to use `else if` for conditions rather than `if` in the `animateSomething` function

Answer (score 0):

In your click action have something like this:

```
$("#container .section strong").css('background-color', 'transparent');
$("#container .section strong:contains('" + $(this).text() + "')").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not look for click actions, I'm leaning more to scrolling things.

Comment: I added it into the click action you had already defined for the bottom navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want exactly, but you could use this to add a class to the every `strong` which is currently in view:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var t = $(this).scrollTop();
    var b = t + $(this).height();
    $('.section>strong').removeClass('highlight').filter(function(){
        var ot = $(this).position().top;
        return ot > t && ot < b;
    }).addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/7/

But it is a bit pointless in my opinion because when it's not in view why do you want to remove the highlight? It won't be visible anyway!?

If you really only want the functionality for section 3 you could change `$('.section>strong')` to `$('#section-3>strong')`

Comment: Actually my point is to do certain things when I'm on a certain section. Highlighting the headings is just an example. I'm seeking for a place to  animate a thing when I'm at a specific thing, like: when on section 2, animate the width of #box to 300px, when on section 3, animate the padding to 10px etc. and so on. Clear enough?